# Performance issue HYPER-V : VM shows very high CPU use, but the Physical machine shows very small CPU use

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, hyper-v

My Hyper-V VM(Server2008R2, SP1) shows very high (almost 100%) CPU use when fully under heavy load (6cores from total physical 8cores, 25Gb RAM from total 32GB) - used as TS, Picture TOP right corner

VM2 (SQL machine, Server 2008R2, SP1) shows almost no CPU use (1 core, 4GB RAM) - picture TOP LEFT

### And funny thing :Physical machine (Bottom picture) has only 1core dedicated out of 8cores + 4GB dedicated out of 32GB just enough to run primary OS and hypervisor) -This physical machine shows almost no load !! for ALL cores of both quad-core CPUs! - Picture on bottom.

Problem/Question :
1, Are my CPUs working on 100%, but it doesnt show the Load which is in VMs? (so here the CPU graph is not correct in terms of "physical machine total CPU use")
- or
2, The CPU graph in Physical machine is correct, and all the Cores are beeing bored and not used for even 10% in the physical machine.(Rooftop of virtualization??)

- or....??

Does anybody has experience with such a performance issue/performance evaluating of Hyper-V VMs vs physical machine?
I just want to know, if all my CPU power is beeing used as it shows in VM...If so I have to get new hardware, if not : My hardware should be fine, only some tweeking might be needed....or?

Picture attached : https://plus.google.com/photos/58146/albums/433/770?banner=pwa&pid=770&oid=58146

LEFT : VM SQL  load (not important)
RIGHT : Application VM 100% load!!!!!
BOTTOM : Physical machine load showing tiny CPU use

Comment: What is the host CPU config, and how many vCPUS have you assigned to the guest? It's not a 1-to-1 comparison when assigning vCPU against host physical hardware.

Comment: You image link seems to be broken.  Can you please re-upload that on http://imgur.com/?

Comment: HI, probably redirected URL, here valid one : https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/HTHOX_Kr6oF9mVBNGKugMIevm7XataxtnMGhBSpe2d0?feat=directlink

Comment: CONFIG : 
Physical machine Dell poweredge 2950 : 2x CPU Xeon 3ghz quadcore, 32Gb RAM, RAID10 4xSAS 15K + 2xSSD for OS and MSSQL.
Application Virtual machine : assigned from total : 6 cores, 25GB, RAID for data, 1xSAS for OS
MSSQL machine : assigned :1 core, 4Gb RAM.

Comment: @Jozef: Did you manage to solve this? (Also Image-Links are dead.)

Answer (score -1):

try this tool to show the real CPU usage of guests:

[image]

http://hyperv.veeam.com/task-manager-hyper-v-announce/

Comment: Hi, thank you, I will give it a try. great!!!
Do you think running this tool on host and guest will show correct-the same results ?

Comment: try it on the host and look if the CPU usage is now displayed correctly.

Comment: HI, seems my OS is not supported... :-( SERVER 2008R2, SP1

Comment: maybe it only works with Server 2012.

Comment: hi, I see that, but both my OS (guest and host) are Server 2008R2, any   tools for this?

Comment: Ask the support of the tool if they can make it 2008R2 compatible.